Exception while using IBM MQ client side with powershell command
I am using IBM MQ nuget package IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.2.0.5. Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 4.8. The nuget package is installed on a project in .NET Standard 2.0.
My application is running fine in Visual Studio 2022 and as a Console application. I am not using any MQClient set up on the machine as its not required by application..
I'm running some .NET services that run  IBM MQ commands like to clear queue or wait for queue to empty. These services are started from powershell script that creates windows processes. A winodows process is created from the exe file provided as an argument in powerhsell. That exe file along its DLLs hold the IBM MQ operations.
My issues is that each time a process runs through powershell, I get an exception in powershell:
'dspmqver' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
However when I read the .NET process logs, there is no exception and according to the logs, the operation finished successfully.
Don't know where this exception is coming from.
Doing a research I found that dspmqver is part of the IBM MQ client set up. But why would I need this setup if my code is running successfully ? also I tried installing the IBM MQC, and adding dspmqver as environment variable as well. the issue still persists, and it's only gone when I put the dspmqver.exe in the same location as the .NET process exe file.
An other confusion to me, on my machine, running these same powershell scripts I have no exceptions, but this exception only shows up on our server used by team city to run these powershell scripts.
Any clue why this happens ? Appreciate any help

It sounds like your code is launching a process to run the "dspmqver.exe" command. If you don't need it, then remove that snippet of code from your program.
